# turn the cursor into a hand when you move the cursor in a clickable direction width phaser 3

Tags: phaser-framework

Can you show me **how to turn the cursor into a hand** when I point the cursor in a clickable direction, but the hand does not appear when I point:

```
balls.getChildren().forEach(
s => s.setInteractive({  cursor: 'url(./src/games/gewgly/assets/images/pointer.png). pointer' 
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the cursor image when the user is hovering over a specific area, you can use input events like [this example](http://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src%5Cinput%5Cmouse%5Ctop%20only%20over%20and%20out%20events.js).

```
this.input.on('gameobjectover', function (pointer, gameObject) {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'url("http://lorempixel.com/23/23/"), default';
});

this.input.on('gameobjectout', function (pointer, gameObject) {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
});
```

Comment: thank you very much, it really helped me and the code works fine,